# posiciones de un string ingresado por consola dart

Tags: array, lista, string, flutter, dart

me acabo de unir, estoy comenzando de cero en dart. Estoy haciendo un ejercicio, donde me piden que el usuario ingrese dos palabras de las cuales tengo que tomar la primera y ultima letra, la primera puedo tomarla con [] en la posicion cero, pero mi duda es, que funcion o que metodo puede ayudarme a conseguir la ultima posicion, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes calcular la cantidad de caracteres de tu texto y restarle menos 1, ya que la enumeración empieza desde 0. Por ejemplo: Luis tiene 4 caracteres, y la letra "s" se encuentra la posición 3 (ya que la letra L es 0, la letra u es 1, ...).

```
void main() {
 final name = 'Luis';

 final firstLetter = name[0];
 final lastLetter = name[name.length - 1];

 print(firstLetter);
 print(lastLetter);
}
```